# Why does my interior paint absorb water and darken when splashed?

Tags: painting

I am wondering if the paint contractors painted my new drywall appropriately.  It is a flat latexand if even brushed with a damp towel it darkens.  It seems to me that the drywall must not have been sealed properly for water to be absorbed like that.  Can you advise me?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the paint returns to the original color once dry, this is perfectly normal with flat latex paints.  When I wipe my walls, the spots that I wipe look darker too.

You can observe this on many surfaces, even inpermuable ones like glass and metal - ever notice that your cars paint looks different when there are drops of water on it?

Comment: Mine look lighter with dark colors.  Always happens when grabbing a towel with wet hands.